# I'm trying to find the sum of all primes below 2 million in python

Tags: python

```
ls = []
total = 0

for i in range(0,2000000):
    ls.append(i)

for i in range(2,2000000):
    for x in range(2,int(float(2000000/i)+0.5)):
        ls[int(float(i*x))] = 0
ls[1] = 0

for j in range(0,2000000):
    total += ls[j]
print total
```

This code is giving me the wrong answer. It includes large numbers that are not prime. It includes 25 more numbers than there are prime numbers.

Comment: You're doing a lot of `float` to `int` conversions. Those are subject to some rounding errors. I'd try to do everything as `int` if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is giving the wrong result, couldn't figure out what approach do you use, it would be better if you could give more details.

There is an algorithm called Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm to generate prime number effectively. You find that algorithm explained [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26562243/4179775), with details to write the algorithm.

```
import math
def primeNumbers(n):
    A = range(2, n + 1) 
    B, C= [],A
    while C[0]< math.sqrt(n): 
        firstElement= C[0]
        B+= [firstElement]
        C= [x for x in C if x%firstElement!=0] 
    return B+C 

t= sum(primeNumbers(2000000)) #you summ the prime numbers numbers 
print t
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
    for x in range(2,int(float(2000000/i)+0.5)):
```

float(2000000/i) doesn't do much in this context, did you mean float(2000000)/i? You're still doing integer division and then converting the result to float. So, when i is 947, this returns 2111.0 instead of 2111.93. As a result, adding 0.5 to that and calling int() effectively does nothing and you still end up with 2111.

This then ends up running the loop till 2110, so you fail to mark 947 * 2111, which gives you a false positive.

You can rewrite the loop slightly to fix this:

```
for i in range(2,2000000):
    for x in range(2 * i, 2000000, i):
        ls[x] = 0
```

This way, instead of dividing and then multiplying, you're simply going through and marking all the multiples of i until 2000000.

Obviously, there are other (better) ways to solve the problem, but I just wanted to point out how you can improve your current solution.